# How to configure maven checkstyle plugin to allow for multiple assignments on a line?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I am using the maven checkstyle plugin and running into this error:

```
InnerAssignment: Inner assignments should be avoided.
```

I read about this error [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#InnerAssignment). Although this check makes sense to me, I would like to configure the plugin so that it does not complain about inner assignments of the form:

```
i = j = k = l = m = 0;
```

which is what I really have in my code. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own rules by providing your own `checkstyle.xml` file as next:

In your `pom` file, configure the plugin as next

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>${pom.basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then take the default `checkstyle.xml` file from [the checkstyle project](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml)  and simply customize it by removing the module `InnerAssignment`. To do so simply remove the following line from your own `checkstyle.xml` file:

```
<module name="InnerAssignment"/>
```

**Response Update:**

Actually the way we can customize this rule cannot fulfill your requirements anyway because you can decide to enable by assign type not by the way you do it. I mean if you decide to disable it for `=` you would actually disable it for `i = j = k = l = m = 0;` but also `String s = Integer.toString(i = 2);` which is not what you want. Moreover I did the test and even what we have in the doc is not working, it seems that this rule is not even configurable, so you keep it as it is or you remove it as proposed above.

Comment: My question is how to customize the InnerAssignment module so that it does not complain about inner assignments of the form `a = b = c = <some value>`.

Comment: I see let me try to improve then

Comment: there is a rule in software development which says "if it is not tested, it is not working" and as you can see it is not tested even in the current master https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/InnerAssignmentCheckTest.java

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I'll keep the question open for few days and accept this as best answer if someone does not come up with a better one.

Comment: I see no problem, do what is the best for you